# Method "of" is not defined - Angular 5 HTTP services tutorial

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'am reading Angular 5 http [tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#handleerror). Everything worked fine, until I stuck on this weird construction wher my Ionic project is throwing error, that "of is not defined".

```
/**
* Handle Http operation that failed.
* Let the app continue.
* @param operation - name of the operation that failed
* @param result - optional value to return as the observable result
*/
private handleError<T> (operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
  return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

    // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
    console.error(error); // log to console instead

    // TODO: better job of transforming error for user consumption
    this.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);

    // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
    return of(result as T);
 };
}
```

I tired googling this "of" method, but with no success. Is this mistake in tutorial? Maybe some library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`of` is a separate function. You need to import `of` function from `rxjs` package. RxJS 5.5 and later use this technique with separate functions. The most of functions you need to import, which lets you to have a clean code and also lets bundle tools to make some optimizations.

```
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of'
```

Answer (score 2):

As shown in example you need to import that method:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
```

See here in page:

[image]